# Is it possible to return an object which can conform to protocol A or protocol B from a generic function?

Tags: swift, protocols

Something like this:

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}

func newObject<T: A, B>(flag: Bool) -> T {
  if flag {
    var aaa: A
    return aaa
  } else {
    var bbb: B
    return bbb
  }
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
'A' is not convertible to 'T'
```

Comment: The reason it fails is you're saying that the return type conforms to both A and B. However, you only return a value that conforms to either A or B, never both. Looks like what you're looking for is return type overloading which from my  understanding doesn't exist. AS an alternative return a tuple of two optionals (A and B) and have the client handle check which one is null and decide which one to use. Honestly, I don't think its a good design choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type you are looking for is called an "Either," and it's easily created in Swift using enums. For example:

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}

enum AorB {
  case IsA(A)
  case IsB(B)
}

func newObject(flag: Bool) -> AorB {
  if flag {
    return .IsA(...create an A...)
  } else {
    return .IsB(...create a B...)
  }
}
```

When creating something like this, you should think very carefully about what your types really mean. What is `AorB` really? It is possible to create a generic holder for this by creating `Either<Left,Right>` (and that's common in some languages), but in many cases there are better names to give to this enum (like `Success` and `Failure` or `Local` and `Remote`). When your types read cleanly, your program is more likely correct.

---

Note that Swift does support return overloading. For example:

```
typealias A = String
typealias B = Int

func newObject() -> A {
  return "a"
}

func newObject() -> B {
  return 1
}

let x:A = newObject()
```

This should be used carefully, however, since it can be pretty awkward for the caller (of course, so is passing a flag…). It makes more sense for functions that are likely to be chained in ways that make type-inference work. In my opinion, if you have a Boolean that flips between two behaviors, what you really have are two functions, and you should strongly lean towards naming them different things.

---

Here's a full working example. The unfortunate `Box` type is a workaround for Beta5. The compiler hasn't yet implemented the ability to store an arbitrary-sized generic object in an enum. It has to know the size at compile time. So we get that with `Box`, which has a known size because it just holds an `[]` (which is what's really boxing for us). By v1 of Swift, you should be able to drop out the `Box` wrapper entirely.

```
protocol A {
  class func create() -> Self
}

class SomethingA : A {
  class func create() -> SomethingA { println("making A"); return SomethingA() }
}

protocol B {
  class func instantiate() -> Self
}

class SomethingB : B {
  class func instantiate() -> SomethingB { println("making B"); return SomethingB() }
}

// Box is because of unimplemented compiler features in beta 5.
struct Box<A> {
  private let box: [A]
  init(_ value: A) { self.box = [value] }
  var value:A { return self.box[0] }
}

enum Either<L,R> {
  case Left(Box<L>)
  case Right(Box<R>)
}

func newObject<L: A, R: B>(flag: Bool) -> Either<L,R> {
  if flag {
    return .Left(Box(L.create()))
  } else {
    return .Right(Box(R.instantiate()))
  }
}


let x:Either<SomethingA,SomethingB> = newObject(true)

switch x {
case .Left(let a): println("I have a: ", a.value, a.value)
case .Right(let b): println("I have b:", b.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the error message above because your return values are only conforming to either protocol A or protocol B. However, your signature states that the return type conforms to both.

Your signature:

```
func newObject<T: A, B>(flag: Bool) -> T
```

can be read as the return type that conforms to both A and B.

What you're actually looking for is return type overloading. From my understanding that doesn't exist. However, you could get around this by returning two optionals as a tuple. Below is a short example of how this would be performed.

```
protocol a{}
protocol b{}

class AnAClass : a{
    var name = "A Class"
}

class AnBClass : b{
    var name = "B Class"
}

func newObject(flag: Bool) -> (a?, b?){
    if flag{
        var aaa: a? = AnAClass()
        return (aaa, nil)
    } else {
        var bbb: b? = AnBClass()
        return (nil, bbb)
    }
}

var tuple = newObject(false)
if let anA = tuple.0 {
    println("We have an A")
} else if let anB = tuple.1{
    println("We have a B");
} else {
    println("Nothing");
}
```

I'll be honest I don't think the above looks clean. I would suggest an alternative, but I'm not fully sure what problem you're trying to solve.